# Apply unique constraint to columns on two separate tables (Django, postgres)

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, unique-constraint

So I'm putting together a site which works a little like github, where both users and organisations have a handle:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """ Using django's default user model, with its username field which looks like:

        username = models.CharField(
            _('username'),
            max_length=150,
            unique=True,
            help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
            validators=[username_validator],
            error_messages={
                'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
            },
        )
    """

    # Many users to many organisations
    organisations = ManyToManyField('Organisation', related_name='users', blank=True)

class Organisation(models.Model):

    # ...other stuff, id etc
    handle = CharField(unique=True, max_length=36, null=False)
```

I'll set up urls with endpoints like `mydomain.com/username_or_handle/stuff`. **This creates conflict, since a user could have the same handle as an organisation.**

**Current solution:**

I have a signal which, on pre-save of either a User or an Organisation, looks up BOTH the tables to ensure uniqueness, and raises a `ValidationError` if its violated.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Organisation)
def check_valid_handle(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """ The abbreviated gist...
    """
    if (Organisation.objects.filter(handle=instance.handle).count() > 0) or (User.objects.filter(username=instance.handle).count() > 0):
        raise ValidationError(detail='This handle is already taken, or prohibited. Please try another.'.format(type_str))
```

But strictly speaking, this could be subject to a race condition, as no lock is applied between the check time and the model creation / update time. Besides, it feels hacky.

Is it possible to apply this constraint at the DB level, without fundamentally altering my models to do multi table inheritance or polymorphism (which could be a nightmare to make work with AbstractUser without a lot of surgery)? And if so, how?

Comment: Have you looked into [multi-table inheritence](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)? I'm not sure if it will play nice with `AbstractUser`

Comment: RE:  "without fundamentally altering my models to inherit from the same base". Not sure about the database level. But you could easily solve this using the validation on the field level validation on the model form or a custom form.

Comment: Also, why do you want to check if the count is greater than 0? if it is greater than 0 it will evaluate to True. so the if condition could just be " if (Organisation.objects.filter(handle=instance.handle).count()  or (User.objects.filter(username=instance.handle).count())"

Comment: @ChetanGanji yup, thanks, totally right about the > 0. Old C++ habits die hard. Validation on the model form (or DRF serialiser, or whatever) would work, but would have the same problem as my current signal of needing to check both tables separately.

Comment: @bdoubleu yes, I had (and polymorphism too). That's definitely a way of achieving what I want, but it's quite major surgery on the database schema, and as you say, I'm concerned about AbstractUser. That's what I meant by 'inherit from the same base' for that reason - edited to clarify Question. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming i understood the problemo right :p, one idea comes to my mind to solve this issue. Have a diff url for the handle 
 of the organisation. E.g. mydomain.com/organisation-id/handle/stuff and for user mydomain.com/username/stuff.

Comment: Otherwise database surgery is imminent 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years later, I've noticed this question had some activity so wanted to post a quasi-answer.

So the strict answer (as emerged in the comments) was "no" it's not straightforward to do this in your database schema.

#### The route I took

In my case, I made `Organisation` derive from django auth's `Group` model.

I also created a `UserGroup` which derived from `Group` and had a 1:1 relationship with User.

I then simply used the `name` field of the Group as the handle, with a unique constraint on there. Job done.

#### Another thing I'd think about

This wasn't available when I wrote the original question, but django now has a much more [powerful constraints system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/) that can be used to apply such constraints on create or update of the models.